# View Width and Height get updated only after it is drawn

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am setting a View's Height at an OnTouch event, later in that event I need to get the Height of that view. The problem is that the event needs to end so the View's Height is updated. Because of that the getHeight() method I call during the event, gives an outdated value.

Is there any way to redraw the view before the event ends or to update the View's params?

Answer (score 0):

You should get this values via posting to a handler of your view..

Try this after you change your view.

```
view.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run() 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "height:"+view.getHeight()+" width: "+view.getWidth());
    }
});
```